# Prove Why is Less than a number equals to this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this word problem

```
68 less than 5 times a number is equal to the number. Find the number.
```

my answer was

$68 - 5x$

but the correct answer was

$5x-68$.

Why is that?

Comment: "($68$ less) than $5\times$ a number ..."

Comment: *less than* is not the same as *minus*.

Comment: then what is the equivalent of minus?

Comment: The question is unclear: it could mean $(68-5)x$ or $68-(5x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You would be right if the question was

```
68 less 5 times a number
```

but the question has the very important *than* which really changes everything. In math, "less than" is backwards. Take for example, the following scenario

```
He makes $2 per hour less than me
```

Then you wouldn't find his salary by subtracting your wage from $2$ would you? You would instead subtract $2$ from your wage since he makes $2$ *less than* you.

So if we come back to your question

```
68 less than 5 times a number
```

and we convert it, to a similar scenario where the question is:

```
He makes 68 less than 5 times what I make
```

then you can see that the answer should be $5x-68$ and not $68-5x$.

For more information check out: [Translating word problems](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/translat.htm)

Answer (score 0):

$68$ less than $5$ times the number.

So you ought to figure out $5$ times the number $(x)=5x$

And then reduce $68$ from this. i.e $5x-68$

Since $5x-68= \ldots \, x=17$.